# DateTimeFormatter can format a date but can't read its own format

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, jackson

I'm trying to parse an ISO-8601 date with a literal `'Z'` on the end.

This will format the date correctly:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
String string = formatter.format(OffsetDateTime.now());
System.out.println(string);
```

Prints:

```
2020-01-19T03:06:58.090Z
```

But then, trying to immediately read it back in:

```
TemporalAccessor acc = formatter.parse(string);
OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.from(acc);
System.out.println(time);
```

Fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=6, MilliOfSecond=90, MicroOfSecond=90000, HourOfAmPm=3, NanoOfSecond=90000000, SecondOfMinute=58},ISO resolved to 2020-01-19 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:370)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:27)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ZoneOffset from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=6, MilliOfSecond=90, MicroOfSecond=90000, HourOfAmPm=3, NanoOfSecond=90000000, SecondOfMinute=58},ISO resolved to 2020-01-19 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.ZoneOffset.from(ZoneOffset.java:348)
    at java.time.OffsetDateTime.from(OffsetDateTime.java:359)
    ... 1 more
```

I cannot change the pattern to use the non-literal `'Z'`, but I noticed that changing it to `Z` so it formats dates with `+0000` on the end can successfully be read in. I also can't change using `TemporalAccessor` to read the date since it's coming from a third party (Jackson). Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you appending a literal `Z` to an `OffsetDateTime` that may have a non-UTC offset?

Comment: If you don't control the input, the format, or the code, how can we possibly help?

Comment: I'm looking to surface dates in UTC. Should I not be using `OffsetDateTime`? What's strange is when I print the `System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.now());` I get a literal `Z` on the end: `2020-01-19T03:24:13.778Z`.

Comment: @shmosel - I control the format, but due to client API requirements it has to be in the format `2020-01-19T03:24:13.778Z`, not `2020-01-19T03:24:13.778+0000`. The code is from Jackson and I'm trying to figure out why it can't parse my `OffsetDateTime `field in one of my objects. I made this small example to share.

Comment: You control the format but have to use a literal `'Z'`? Why?

Comment: It's the format my client's API is producing and I'm attempting to read it in

Comment: I meant the pattern string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using a literal `'Z'`, there's no time zone in the data, so you'll have to specify one manually:

```
OffsetDateTime time = LocalDateTime.from(acc).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: This highlights my issue, I should be using LocalDateTime and not OffsetDateTime. Thank you

Comment: Or `ZonedDateTime` with a format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz`. Or an `Instant`. It would help to include some more context. But if `LocalDateTime` does the job, by all means.

Comment: Wrong answer, or at least not ideal. You should use either `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant`. You don't need any formatter, and if you use one, you must never hardcode `Z` as a Literal. Use pattern letter uppercase `X` for formatting and parsing it.

Comment: And congrats on the 40 k.

Answer (score 2):

### The Z is not a literal

The `Z` in the ISO 8601 format is an offset of zero from UTC (also known as *Zulu time zone*). You need to format and parse it as such, or you will get incorrect results. `OffsetDateTime.now()` may and usually does return a date-time with a non-zero offset. When you are printing it with a `Z` as offset, you are printing incorrect information, a different point in time.

> I cannot change the pattern to use the non-literal 'Z',

I hope I misunderstood this part. It sounds to me like you have got an error that you cannot fix.

### You need no formatter

`OffsetDateTime` and the other date and time classes from java.time print ISO 8601 format from their `toString` methods and parse the same format back. So you don’t need to specify any formatter explicitly.

Possibly the `Instant` class fits your requirements better than `OffsetDateTime`. An `Instant` is a point in time independent of time zone and offset. Its `toString` method generates an ISO 8601 string in UTC and therefore always with the `Z` in the end.

```
    String string = Instant.now().toString();
    System.out.println(string);

    // Parse back
    Instant time = Instant.parse(string);
    System.out.println(time);
```

When I ran this just now, the output was:

> ```
> 2020-01-19T05:37:29.630135Z
> 2020-01-19T05:37:29.630135Z
> ```

If you can require your incoming date-time string to have a `Z` as offset always, I should say that this is the solution for you. You can always convert the `Instant` to a different type after parsing if you need.

If you prefer `OffsetDateTime`:

```
    String string = OffsetDateTime.now().toString();
    System.out.println(string);

    // Parse back
    OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.parse(string);
    System.out.println(time);
```

Example output from my time zone:

> ```
> 2020-01-19T06:37:29.721666+01:00
> 2020-01-19T06:37:29.721666+01:00
> ```

You notice that the correct offset for my time zone, `+01:00`, is printed rather than `Z`, which goes nicely to illustrate that the `Z` would have been incorrect. If you want the UTC time, just tell `OffsetDateTime` so by passing `ZoneOffseet.UTC` to the `now` method:

```
        String string = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString();
        System.out.println(string);
```

> ```
> 2020-01-19T05:43:06.700402Z
> ```

Parsing back works as before.